# Unable to identify operative event or method in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I need help identifying what piece of code is causing a bug in my app but having a hard time working it out.

So, my app is designed to display a detail screen for any row that is selected in the master table.

I have recently updated my app to use an *NSFetchResultsController*. The results are what I would expect except for one odd behaviour.

The new behaviour happens when I select a row in the master table, prior to the segue to the detail screen.

The table populates with all the data I would expect. But, on clicking any row in the table (other than the first one), each field in the row is set to the default values that appear in the storyboard.

The segue to the detail screen displays the expected details and the underlying database table is also correct.

I have a segue outlet action on the cell but no other method.

Despite placing breakpoints at various points in the code, I cannot identify which code section is triggering the setting of the row to the storyboard defaults.

I'd appreciate any steer that would help me work this out.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my question as relative newbie to xCode. I've now discovered the profiling tools built into xCode and have been able to identify what's happening in my code with more confidence.